# Auto scroll Icons in div based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this working but it's moving every picture on the page not just the ones I want.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var parent = $('#parent');
var img = $('img:first-child');

parent.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX
    console.log(mouseX/parent.width()*100);
    img.css('margin-left',-mouseX/parent.width()*100);

});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

The icons code is:

```
<div id="parent">

      <div id="propertyThumbnails">

  <a href="#"><img src= "icons/Facebook.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src= "icons/Twitter.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src= "icons/Google.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src= "icons/Digg.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src= "icons/LinkedIn.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src= "icons/Tumblr.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src= "icons/Pinterest.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src= "icons/YouTube.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src= "icons/OtherSite.png" width="24" height="24"></a>
</div></div>
```

Any idea how to just scroll the ones I want not every image on the page?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var parent = $('#parent');
var img = parent.find('a > img:first-child');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery will select all of the images because all of the `<img>` tags are first child of `<a>`. You need to use a more specific select, like:

`$('a:first-child > img')`